# AutoComplete/Intellisense in VS 2010 (opened with WebMatrix) for @Model.[NAME]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

Not specifically an Orchard CMS question, but I use Orchard.Web (pre-compilation) in WebMatrix and then click to open in VS2010.

There is no build, I get that.

But is there a way to get the autocomplete/intellisense (not sure what it's called), so that within a View.cshtml when I insert "using Model" and then "@model Model" on the top, and then within my Html.BeginForm when I type "@Model.[NAME]" I get options for which NAME I want to use?

Or am I off base and out of luck? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `Model` really the name of your model?  At the top of your view you should have:

```
@model YourModelClassName
```

And to access your Model's properties, you'd do something like `YourModelClassName.YourProperty`.

> when I type "@Model.[NAME]" I get options for which NAME I want to use?

By that quote, are you thinking you'll be able to access what would be stored in the `NAME` property of your Model?  Intellisense won't give you that.  That's only available at the runtime.

**Edit** You need to build your project before your View can utilize Intellisense.

Comment: No, sorry just simplifying things. It is @model MyModelClassName.

Comment: @REMESQ Are you trying to access what is *stored* in the `NAME` property?  You can't do that until runtime.

Comment: Again, sorry, just using the brackets to indicate a unique name. Ok, so I am out of luck. Referencing MyModelClassName in the view and then typing "Model." in the Html.Begin form section of the view will NOT bring me a list of the items in MyModelClassName. Thanks for the clarification. I have to figure out a way to make this easier, I have like 40 items and cannot remember each name. Using the IDE and having a new vertical/horizontal tab group with he Model.cs file open might be my only bet.

Comment: @REMESQ Try Building your Project and then try the Intellisense.  I have seen where Models aren't recognized until after they are built.

Comment: Using Orchard.Web. Building the Source is cumbersome and winds up giving me a huge file.

Comment: @REMESQ I do believe that is what you need to do in order to have Intellisence on your Model through your View.

Comment: Since I am using Orchard.Web and not compiling this won't work. Compiling creates huge /bin files so I am trying to avoid that. I've gone old school and am just using a new vertical tab well and minimizing all the items so I can see their names.